# AngularJS How do i sort all posts across all the pages?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to sort all posts by pubdate across all the pages. Before asking, I tried, but it didn't work out. My solution works only in the first page.
What I did wrong? Why this `orderBy: '-pubdate'` don't work correctly? 
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7fqew8s5/2/ 
Thanks for any help. 
P.S. Sorry for my English. I'm Ukrainian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply sort the array `$scope.items` will solve this issue :

A working jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/yufeng/5wz6nxun/

```
//Add the following code after the declaration of $scope.items
//sort the items by 'pubdate'
$scope.items.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.pubdate - a.pubdate;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.